# Python diffent line display different print outputs asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I want to know how could I print different values to the different display area in one console.

For example:

```py
Hello, world! # 100 times
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Hi, world! # 20 times
```

How could make the output console display like this? As if I have two screens, each one display a single output. 
These two parts are shown in this console at the same time. But updates its own value at different time. The outputs are always displaying on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `curses` module: [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#)

An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(True)

stdscr.refresh()
begin_x = 0; begin_y = 0
height = 10; width = 80;

win1 = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)
win2 = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y + 11, begin_x)

for i in range(1,9):
    win1.addstr(i, 0, "Hello {0}\n".format(i))
    win1.refresh()

for i in range(1,9):
    win2.addstr(i, 0, "World {0}\n".format(i))
    win2.refresh()

while True:
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c == ord('q'):
        break

stdscr.keypad(False)
curses.nocbreak()
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```